# How to create local notification in react native and android

Tags: android, notifications, react-native

I am trying to create a local notification in android using react-native. My application is completely local, so I don't want to use GCM or FCM. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868809/how-to-create-multiple-local-notifications-in-android) where it is done using java. Is there wrapper or a library in React Native to achieve the same?

I also saw `PushNotificationIOS` API, will it work with Android?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, react-native-push-notifications.  It does local notifications too on both iOS and Android.

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Comment: I don't want GCM features as I'm not gonna use it. Is there a simple library which can achieve only local notifications?

Comment: You can use react-native-push-notification library to send local notifications on both iOS and Android.

Comment: This library sucks - see issue below with no solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63144729/react-native-push-notification-android-notification-keeps-repeating-and-wont

Answer (score 3):

Wix has the best plugin for notifications.

Includes **Local Notifications** AND **Push** (Android & iOS)

https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications

If you don't want to use push, you can skip the configuration and just install & link to start using

```
npm install --save react-native-notifications
react-native link react-native-notifications
```

Take a look at the install guide: https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications/blob/master/docs/installation.md

Example of use

```
let localNotification = NotificationsIOS.localNotification({
    body: "Local notificiation!",
    title: "Local Notification Title",
    sound: "chime.aiff",
    silent: false,
    category: "SOME_CATEGORY",
    userInfo: { }
});

NotificationsAndroid.localNotification({
    title: "Local notification",
    body: "This notification was generated by the app!",
    extra: "data"
});
```

You can find more information on local notifications at https://wix.github.io/react-native-notifications/docs/localNotifications

**Also, the notifications layout can be fully customized on Android**

Comment: Wix plugin doesn't work for android. As soon as I added wix react-native-notifications android app crashes though iOS works properly

Comment: The link to the local notifications doesn't work and those three parameters to create the Android notifications are not enough.

Comment: Here is the link https://wix.github.io/react-native-notifications/docs/localNotifications

Comment: Anyone got the wix's react-native-notifications plugin work for Local Notifications on Android?

Comment: any updates on this? android docs are very limited, how to customize local notification? how to add image? setup actions?...

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification to handle local notification.  You can use it with out GCM dependencies. Read through **[Usage](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#usage)** section GCM and scheduled notifications are optional.  I am using this with Jobscheduler to avoid FCM dependencies.

Comment: I have a question, I'm developing two apps first of the user app and second to providers, in user app, I made some function to send order and saved into real-time database firebase t and in the second app I just retrieve the data from DB with a listener to get the new order as a real-time without refreshing the app, SO I want to when I send an order from user app to firebase I want to display a notify in the second app? How to handle these

Comment: the major problem is the installation, there is not much clear docs, if you don't want to use the firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [Notifee](https://notifee.app/) library.

> Notifee enables developers to rapidly build rich notifications with a simple API interface, whilst taking care of complex problems such as scheduling, background tasks, device API compatibility & more.